# Function equivalent to prepending string with "r" in Python

Tags: python, string

It's great that I can write

```
s = r"some line\n"
```

but what is the functional equivalent to preprending with `r`? For example:

```
s = raw_rep( s )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one. The `r` is an integral part of the [string literal token](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), and omitting it is a lossy operation.

For example, `r'\n'`, `r'\12'` and `r'\x0a'` are three different strings. However, if you omit the `r`, they become identical, making it impossible to tell which of the three it was to begin with.

For this reason, this is no method that would reconstruct the original string 100% of the time.

Comment: I understand your example. Is there a workaround? What if I don't care what the original string is, is there a workaround?

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: json.loads some data with escape characters. ex: `json.loads( """{"data":"aefea\n"}""" )` will fail.

Answer (score 2):

```
def raw_rep(s):
    quote = '"' if "'" in s else "'"
    return 'r' + quote + s + quote

>>> print raw_rep(r'some line\n')
r'some line\n'
```